# Integration of forms does not depend on choice of local coordinates?

Tags: integration, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

> Let $M$ be an oriented $k$-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n,$ where $1\leq k \leq n.$ Let $\omega$ be a continuous $k$-form in $\mathbb{R}^n$, vanishing outside a compact set $K$. Suppose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are local coordinates for $M$, and $K \subset \tilde{U_\alpha} \cap \tilde{U_\beta}.$ Then $\int_{{V_\alpha}}\alpha^*(\omega)=\int_{{V_\beta}}\beta^*(\omega)$.

This is lemma $14.9$ in *Mathematical Analysis* by Andrew Browder. To prove it, he states first that $\int_{{V_\beta}}\beta^*(\omega)=\int_{{V_{\alpha\beta}}}\beta^*(\omega),$ where $V_{\beta}=\beta^{-1}(U_\beta)$ and $V_{\alpha \beta} = \beta^{-1}(U_\alpha \cap U_\beta)$. My guess is this equality holds because of compact support, but I am unable to work out the details. *Why* does it hold?

Comment: The support of $\omega$ is contained in $K$. However, $K\subseteq U_\alpha \cap U_\beta$ (I think you have some tildes too many in the first part) and hence, we can restrict the integration to $\beta^{-1}(K) \subseteq \beta^{-1}(U_\alpha \cap U_\beta)$.

Comment: Probably it is the easiest to write out what $\beta^*(\omega)$ actually is (then you can easily see where it is supported).

Comment: Ah, so the reason is that the integral is just $0$ outside $\beta^{-1}(K)$? Since $\beta^{-1}(K) \subseteq \beta^{-1}(U_\alpha \cap U_\beta) = \beta^{-1}(U_\alpha) \cap \beta^{-1}(U_\beta) \subseteq \beta^{-1}(U_\beta),$ we can just integrate over $\beta^{-1}(U_\alpha \cap U_\beta)$?

Comment: I did write out the definition of $\beta^*(\omega)$ but I'm not sure what it even means. At the point $\mathbf{p}$ and applied to $\mathbf{v}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{v}_r,$ it is just ${(\beta^*\omega)}_{\mathbf{p}}(\mathbf{v}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{v}_r)=\omega_{\mathbf{f(p)}}(\mathbf{\beta'(p)v}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{\beta'(p)v}_r)$?

Comment: Exactly, because $\omega_q \equiv 0$ for $q\notin K$ (as $\omega$ is only supported in $K$). Note that in your formula it should be $\omega_{\beta(p)}$.

Comment: Thank you so much, makes perfect sense now!

Comment: I encourage you to write up a detailed answer. This way you can be sure that you truly understood what is going on and the next person that has a similar problem can profit from your insight.

Comment: I will, but I have one more clarification. Why does the author consider $\tilde{U_\alpha} \cap \tilde{U_\beta}$ as you hinted at? Here, I think $\tilde{U_\alpha}$ means that $U_\alpha$ is open in the relative topology of $M$ (so $\mathbb{R}^n$) and  $U_\alpha = \tilde{U_\alpha} \cap M$? Why not just $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta$?

Comment: That is because we pick a differential form in $\mathbb{R}^n$, its support needs not be contained in $M$. At the end of the day it does not matter too much, but we cannot hope to write $K\subseteq U_\alpha \subseteq M$.

Comment: I just wrote my answer, thank you so much again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$\beta^{-1}(K) \subseteq \beta^{-1}(\tilde{U}_\alpha \cap \tilde{U_\beta)} = \beta^{-1}(\tilde{U}_\alpha) \cap \beta^{-1}(\tilde{U}_\beta) \subseteq \beta^{-1}(\tilde{U}_\beta).$$
Suppose $\mathbf{p} \in \tilde{V}_{\beta}$. Note that $\mathbf{p} \notin \beta^{-1}(K)$ implies that $\beta(\mathbf{p}) \notin K$. Thus,
$${(\beta^*\omega)}_{\mathbf{p}}(\mathbf{v}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{v}_r)=\omega_{\mathbf{\beta(p)}}(\mathbf{\beta'(p)v}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{\beta'(p)v}_r)=0,$$
since $\omega$ vanishes outside of $K.$ Therefore,
$$\int_{{V_\beta={\beta^{-1}(\tilde{U}_\beta)}}}\beta^*(\omega)=\int_{{V_{\alpha\beta}={\beta^{-1}(\tilde{U}_\alpha \cap \tilde{U_\beta)}}}}\beta^*(\omega),$$
as the integral vanishes for all points $\mathbf{p}$ outside $\beta^{-1}(K)$!